# putting if statement in api with laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, logic, form-submit

I'm currently learning on how API works and my mentor gave me a task to create submit the form using API and store the data on database with laravel and the task also require mandatory if logic on some field.

I have succeeded with the first task (storing data to the database ) and I'm having difficulties writing the mandatory if.

I'm confused, on my task paper I'm told to create one controller, one model and two endpoints (request-schedule and request-leaving) where each endpoint should have some parameters.

and for the request-leaving parameter, there are 10 parameters, 6 of them have this requirement like (mandatory if request type Request Day Off)

There are 3 requests typewritten on there 
1. Request Day off 
2. Request Schedule
3. Change Schedule

I'm a super newbie in programming, does anyone know how to solve this?

```php
public function CreateReqSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $reqschedule = new B777();

    $reqschedule->reqtype = $request->input('reqtype');
    $reqschedule->startdate = $request->input('startdate');
    $reqschedule->enddate = $request->input('enddate');
    $reqschedule->reason = $request->input('reason');
    $reqschedule->route = $request->input('route');
    $reqschedule->actualschedule = $request->input('actualschedule');
    $reqschedule->changetoschedule = $request->input('changetoschedule');
    $reqschedule->swapcrewid = $request->input('swapcrewid');
    $reqschedule->swapcrewschedule = $request->input('swapcrewschedule');
    $reqschedule->note = $request->input('note');

    $reqschedule->save();

    return response()->json($reqschedule);
}
```

code above is my only work, I'm feeling anxious, because I've googled it myself but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Being mandatory means, I believe it's about validation. right?

Comment: since you're using API, then you need to create manual validation, so it will returning a json response instead of error pages,  you can wrap it inside if statement , validation detail read in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: Laravel handles the situation based on request, whether it is json request or html request.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan yes its about validation.

Answer (score 0):

So you are talking about validations. you can put laravel validation into it like below

Use `required` validation for mandotory data and return response in json

```
// Making validation for fields
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'fields1' => 'required',
    'fields2' => 'required',
    'fields3' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    // return response on validaton fails
    return response()->json(['status'=>400,'errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
}
// If validation passes store your data in database
```